# TTL settings for rollups tables in OpsCenter keyspace?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

By Default, rollups tables like rollup360, rollup60, rollup7200, rollup86400 have value 0 for default_time_to_live which means the data never expires. But as per [Opscenter Metrics blog](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/metric-collection-and-storage-with-cassandra) Using Cassandra’s built in ttl support, OpsCenter expires the columns in the rollups60 column family after 7 days, the rollups300 column family after 4 weeks, the rollups 7200 column family after 1 year, and the data in the rollups86400 column family never expires.

1. What is the reason behind this setting and Where do we set the TTL for these tables?
2. Since OpsCenter data is growing, shouldn't we have TTLs defined for
   rollups tables at the table level?

But in opscenterd.conf default values are listed below.

```
[cassandra_metrics]
1min_ttl = 86400 
5min_ttl = 604800
2hr_ttl = 2419200
```

Which settings has preference over the other?

Comment: insert time ttls. Check them by using ttl(field name) in your select statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are defaults if not set anywhere defined in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/configure/opscMetricsConfig_r.html):

> 1min_ttl  Sets the time in seconds to expire 1
>   minute data points. The default value is 604800 (7 days).
>
> 5min_ttl  Sets the time in seconds to expire 5
>   minute data points. The default value is 2419200 (28 days).
>
> 2hr_ttl  Sets the time in seconds to expire 2 hour
>   data points. The default value is 31536000 (365 days).
>
> 24hr_ttl  Sets the time to expire 24 hour data
>   points. The default value is 0, or never.

If you dont set them it will use the defaults, but if you override them in the `[cassandra_metrics]` section of the `opscenterd.conf`. When the agent on the node stores a rollup for a period it will include whatever TTL its associated with, ie (not exactly how opscenter does it but for demonstration purposes):

```
INSERT INTO rollups60 (key, timestamp, value) VALUES (...) USING TTL 604800;
```

In your example you lowered the TTLs which would decrease the amount of data stored. So for:

1) You set lower TTL to decrease amount of data stored on disk. You can configure it as you mentioned in your ticket. Although the compaction strategy can affect this significantly.

2) There is a default ttl setting on the tables, but there really isn't much difference between setting it per query and having it in the table. Doing an alter table is pretty expensive if need to change it compared to just changing the value of the ttl on the inserts. If having issues with obsolete data in tables try switching to `LeveledCompactionStrategy` (not this increases IO on compactions but probably not noticeable)

Answer (score 0):

According to : 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/configure/opscChangingPerformanceDataExpiration_t.html

"Edit the cluster_name.conf file."

Chris, you suggested to edit the opscenterd.conf.